# Replace all occurrence of character except first one

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a text file as follows:

```
test1,test2,test3
test4,test5
test6,test7,test8,test9,test10
test11,test12,test13,test14
```

How can I replace commas with semicolons,
*starting with the second one* (and continuing to the last one)?

I want to get output as follows:

```
test1,test2;test3
test4,test5
test6,test7;test8;test9;test10
test11,test12;test13;test14
```

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question body. Do you want nth to (or through) mth, or do you want nth through last, no matter how many there are? And do you specifically want 2nd through last, or do you want a general solution that can easily be changed to substitute the 4th through the last, or the 17th through the last?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the input might already have semicolons in it, we have to be careful:

```
$ sed 's/,/\n/g; s/\n/,/; s/\n/;/g' input
test1,test2;test3
test4,test5
test6,test7;test8;test9;test10
test11,test12;test13;test14
```

Since sed reads the input line-by-line, there will be no newline characters in normal input.  So, we can replace all the commas with newlines and we know that there will be no confusion.  Next we restore the first newline back to a comma.  Lastly, we replace all remaining newlines with a semicolon.

In more detail:

- `s/,/\n/g` replaces all commas with newlines.
- `s/\n/,/` replaces the first newline with a comma.
- `s/\n/;/g` replaces all remaining newlines with semicolons.

Comment: I thought of ```sed 's/,/\n/; s/,/;/g; s/\n/,/'```, which is very similar to your answer, except mine has only one `g`lobal command. Can you identify a situation where your command works better than mine?

Answer (score 14):

This can be done with this,

```
$ sed -e 's/,/;/g' -e 's/;/,/1' infile
test1,test2;test3
test4,test5
test6,test7;test8;test9;test10
test11,test12;test13;test14
```

**Explanation**

- `s/,/;/g` replaces all occurrence of `,` with `;`
- `s/;/,/1` replaces the first occurrence of `;` with `,`

---

If you have GNU `sed`, you can also try this simple and handy,

```
sed 's/,/;/2g' infile
```

Comment: didn't know about `sed 's/,/;/2g'` on GNU sed, cool one!

Comment: What I don't like about this solution is that it breaks down unexpectedly when you replace "test1" with a string containing a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(",", ";"); sub(";", ","); print}' file.txt
```

- `gsub(",", ";")` replaces all `,` with `;`
- `sub(";", ",")` replaces the first `;` with `,`

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
test1,test2,test3
test4,test5
test6,test7,test8,test9,test10
test11,test12,test13,test14

% awk '{gsub(",", ";"); sub(";", ","); print}' file.txt
test1,test2;test3
test4,test5
test6,test7;test8;test9;test10
test11,test12;test13;test14
```

Comment: If the question is to keep the first two semicolon, you can add another sub function.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
$ cat ip.txt 
test1,test2,test3
test4,test5
test6,test7,test8,test9,test10
test11,test12,test13,test14
test15

$ perl -F, -ane 'print "$F[0]"; print ",".join(";",@F[1..$#F]) if($#F > 0)' ip.txt 
test1,test2;test3
test4,test5
test6,test7;test8;test9;test10
test11,test12;test13;test14
test15
```

Another way:

```bsh
perl -F'/(,)/,$_,2' -ane '$F[2] =~ s/,/;/g; print @F'
```

- `/(,)/,$_,2` split `$_` (the input line) into two based on `,` Since `(,)` is used, it captures the separator as well resulting in three elements as explained below
- `$F[0]` gets first field, `$F[1]` will get `,` if present
- `$F[2]` gets remaining fields if present

Yet another way, emulating `sed 's/,/;/2g'`

```bsh
perl -pe '$c=0; s/,/++$c<2 ? $& : ";"/ge' ip.txt
```

- initialize counter for every line
- when substituting, check counter value as needed
- the `e` modifier allows Perl code in replacement section